# How to change a node's term reference value, dependant on date

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type "Page" and one of its fields is a term reference to the taxonomy term "Page Type"

Another field is "Expiry Date"

The page type starts off as "Open Consultation", but I need it to automatically change the term reference to "Closed Consultation" if the "Expiry Date" has passed.

I've been a developer for years, but I'm still quite new to Drupal (7)... I know the GUI, but not php or which files to override (if that is the answer)

So, I need a basic explanation of how to achieve this.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Computed Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field), I'm not sure if can handle the date field type or not. on the other hand if Computed Field didn't do what you want you could do a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook in your custom module. and code your logic there.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that the answer would be using hook_form_alter, but can you give me any direction on the code logic ?